# Get changes in a Task List in Sharepoint Online through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0, sharepoint-online

I am trying to find out the changes that are made to a task list in sharepoint online with the help of CSOM. (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll) I was able to query for changes through the GetChanges method of the List class but not sure what to do further. I am specifically looking for how to get information related to list changes in specific columns, the old values, the new values, the user who made the change and etc. Is this even possible? I am aware of the Change.ChangeToken property but I am not sure how to implement it in PowerShell. Here is my incomplete code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$scriptdir\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$context.RequestTimeOut = 1000 * 60 * 10;
$context.AuthenticationMode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode]::Default
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
$context.Credentials = $credentials
$web = $context.Web  
$site = $context.Site
$context.Load($web)  
$context.Load($site) 
$context.ExecuteQuery()
Set-Variable -Name "clientContext" -Value $context -Scope Global
Set-Variable -Name "rootSiteUrl" -Value $siteURL -Scope Global
Function Get-ListChanges {   
    $listName = "Tasks"
    $list = $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
    $cq = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeQuery($true,$true)
    $changes = $list.GetChanges($cq)
    $clientContext.Load($changes)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    $changes.count
    foreach ($item in $changes) {   
        # get data here from specific column name/old values/newvalues
    }   
}
```

Thank you for looking in to this!

UPDATE:
As requested, result of $item.GetType() for a single Change item...

```
Module                     : System.Management.Automation.dll
Assembly                   : System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
TypeHandle                 : System.RuntimeTypeHandle
DeclaringMethod            :
BaseType                   : System.Object
UnderlyingSystemType       : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
FullName                   : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
AssemblyQualifiedName      : System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
                             PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Namespace                  : System.Management.Automation
GUID                       : 5f6aa156-8585-35c9-a6ae-2aefd06aaa4a
IsEnum                     : False
GenericParameterAttributes :
IsSecurityCritical         : True
IsSecuritySafeCritical     : False
IsSecurityTransparent      : False
IsGenericTypeDefinition    : False
IsGenericParameter         : False
GenericParameterPosition   :
IsGenericType              : False
IsConstructedGenericType   : False
ContainsGenericParameters  : False
StructLayoutAttribute      : System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute
Name                       : PSCustomObject
MemberType                 : TypeInfo
DeclaringType              :
ReflectedType              :
MetadataToken              : 33554762
GenericTypeParameters      : {}
DeclaredConstructors       : {Void .cctor(), Void .ctor()}
DeclaredEvents             : {}
DeclaredFields             : {SelfInstance}
DeclaredMembers            : {System.String ToString(), Void .cctor(), Void .ctor(), SelfInstance}
DeclaredMethods            : {System.String ToString()}
DeclaredNestedTypes        : {}
DeclaredProperties         : {}
ImplementedInterfaces      : {}
TypeInitializer            : Void .cctor()
IsNested                   : False
Attributes                 : AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, BeforeFieldInit
IsVisible                  : True
IsNotPublic                : False
IsPublic                   : True
IsNestedPublic             : False
IsNestedPrivate            : False
IsNestedFamily             : False
IsNestedAssembly           : False
IsNestedFamANDAssem        : False
IsNestedFamORAssem         : False
IsAutoLayout               : True
IsLayoutSequential         : False
IsExplicitLayout           : False
IsClass                    : True
IsInterface                : False
IsValueType                : False
IsAbstract                 : False
IsSealed                   : False
IsSpecialName              : False
IsImport                   : False
IsSerializable             : False
IsAnsiClass                : True
IsUnicodeClass             : False
IsAutoClass                : False
IsArray                    : False
IsByRef                    : False
IsPointer                  : False
IsPrimitive                : False
IsCOMObject                : False
HasElementType             : False
IsContextful               : False
IsMarshalByRef             : False
GenericTypeArguments       : {}
CustomAttributes           : {}
```

Comment: could you post the type (`$item.getType()`) of such a change item so we can have a look at the properties?

Comment: @Paul see change above

Answer (score 1):

Tank, it's possible to get the change type and the change time:

```
$item | Select ChangeType,Time
```

I may be taking a stab in the dark but you might want to investigate the ChangeLogItemQuery class.  It might be able to give you more information about the actual change itself (Old/New etc).  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

More info on ChangeLogItemQuery class here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changelogitemquery_members(v=office.15).aspx